# TV turned on when chromecast app receiver is loaded

Tags: google-cast

I developped a chromecast receiver application that simply loads a web page from a local web server. The default app being the Backdrop, when the latter is launched (e.g. after the chromecast is turned on), I simply launch my app by its registered app id.

For some reason, if the TV is turned off, and the chromecast switches from the Backdrop to my receiver app, the TV turns on and shows the loaded page. I suspect this is a CEC related issue, but I wonder why this doesn't happen with the Backdrop too?

The only code I use in the receiver page is:

```
<script>
cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance().start();
</script>
```

I'm using the API v2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the typical use of the Cast SDK so its likely you might run into issues. CEC is used for turning on TV's when it makes sense but unfortunately doesn't work consistently good across various manufacturers.